# incorrect syntax near '*'

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error

I was trying to execute one of my Stored procedure but i am getting an syntax error and i am unable to understand why.

here is the sproc:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HotlinePlusAdministration_ArticleMigrator]
            @ArticleKey AS INT,
            --@CategoryID AS INT,
            --@Title AS Varchar(200),
            --@ArticleDate AS datetime,
            @DestLinkServer AS VARCHAR(50),
            @UserID     AS VARCHAR(8),
            @ReturnMsg AS VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT
    AS

    BEGIN

    DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @Log AS VARCHAR(8000)
    DECLARE @ArticleID as int
    DECLARE @NewArticleID as int
    DECLARE @ArticleKeyExists as int
    DECLARE @Title as varchar(200)
    DECLARE @CategoryID  as INT
    DECLARE @ArticleDate  as varchar(30)
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

    SET XACT_ABORT ON -- Required for nested transaction
    BEGIN TRAN


    -- Check if ArticleID exists in Destination Server

      SET @Query =  N'  SELECT    @ArticleKeyExists = COUNT(*)
                           FROM ' +   @DestLinkServer + '.HL2_61.dbo.Article' + ' where ArticleKey = ' + str(@ArticleKey)

            SET @ParmDefinition =  N'@ArticleKey int,  @ArticleKeyExists int OUTPUT';

            EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query , @ParmDefinition, @ArticleKey ,  @ArticleKeyExists  OUTPUT;

                         IF @@ERROR <> 0
                             BEGIN 
                                     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                                SET @ReturnMsg = @Log + '<span style="color:red;">ERROR: <br></span>'
                                    RETURN -1
                            END


    --Delete existing Articles for select page
    set @Query = 'DELETE FROM ' + @DestLinkServer + 
                '.HL2_61.dbo.Article ' +
                 'WHERE ArticleKey = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @ArticleKey)
                --'WHERE CategoryID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CategoryID)  + ' and Title = ''' + @Title + '''  and ArticleDate  = ''' + @ArticleDate  + ''''
    Print @Query
    EXEC(@Query)
```

when i am trying to execute it i am getting an error here:

```
SELECT    @ArticleKeyExists = COUNT(*)
                       FROM BRWSQLDC.HL2_61.dbo.Article where ArticleKey = 1591276581
```

Can some body please help me on this,

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with @ArticleKeyExists = COUNT(*)?

Comment: i am trying to check if the linked server has that value init and if so i will delete the row and insert new value which i am trying to send

Answer (score 1):

SET @ArticleKeyExists = (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM BRWSQLDC.HL2_61.dbo.Article where ArticleKey = 1591276581)

Comment: +1 Yep, you can't ignore the SELECT part and use COUNT on it's own for a recordset.